# Intel Matrix Raid and Raid5

Tags: raid-5

I suffered failed raid0 and now I'm buying 3x1TB drives to setup raid5 on Intel matrix storage manager that comes with my MoBo (Ausus 5pk-e).
The questions is: how safe am I with the decision (raid5 on IMSM)? What I am specifically concerned about: what is going to happen if mobo dies, what can be done to recover the data if, suppose, my PC lives for 5 more years (it's around 4 years old already). Would I need to search for some used pc with the same controller, or I'll be OK with any other raid board and my raid5 drives would be properly recognized?

Comment: Using the backups you make regularly would be an option if things failed.  RAID of any kind is not a backup.

Comment: @Dave M is correct that RAID is no substitute for backups (e.g. consider theft of the desktop, or fire, ...).  As for Intel fake RAID: You need the same (type) of motherboard. Assume that you can no longer access the data when the  motherboard fails. If you do not make regular backups, consider software RAID (via drivers, not via Intel fake RAID) or hardware RAID. (The latter is better, often faster and a problem if your RAID card dies).

Comment: Backups isn't an option. I move around and modify gigs of data and I really want to be back and running in no time if a drive fails. Basically, with intel raid I'll need to get same mobo if it fails to recover the data. Aren't there some sort of compatibility between different raid manufacturers?

Answer (score 0):

Generally is it not recommended to run RAID5 using a software based solution.  Perhaps better to identify what data needs to be mirrored and for the same capacity run 2 disks in RAID1 and one not in RAID.  This will be better for reliability and performance.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not about making backups, go for RIAD-60 - this is only way to save you (from data loss)

Comment: RAID protects you from disk failure - it does not safeguard against data loss.  RAID is not backup.

Comment: DOAH. I know, but if YOU will read author's comments you will notice that he is not willing to make backups. And raid 60 is the most secure disk matrix available. DownVote not needed - read all comments, then make any move.

Comment: The fact remains whether the OP choose to backup or not.

Comment: How do you do RAID 60 with only 3 drives? RAID 6 is impossible with 3 drives.

Comment: Of course not, but as before I've posted most secure way to store data without making backups.